# Как сгенерировать одноразовую ссылку на скачивание файла в Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Как реализовать одноразовую персональную ссылку на скачивание файла через фласк.Желательно самый простой пример.

Comment: Здравствуйте! На Стак Оверфлоу принято выкладывать попытки решения своей проблемы, чтобы мы могли вам помочь. Вы можете исправить свой вопрос кнопкой [edit].

Comment: Сгенерировать какой-нибудь уникальный ключ, положить его в базу, добавить обработчик ссылки с приёмом ключа, в обработчике проверить наличие ключа в базе, удалить ключ и отдать файл